# Do the weakly null sequences in a Banach module factor?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with a bounded approximate identity, and let $E$ be a Banach left $A$-module. Suppose neither $A$ nor $E$ has the Schur property.

**Question:** Given a weakly null sequence $(w_n)$ in $E$, does there exist

- a weakly null sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$
- a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ in $E$

such that $w_n = a_nx_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; here's a counter-example.  Let $E$ be some Banach space without the [Schur Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_property), give $E$ the zero product, and let $A=E\oplus\mathbb C$ be the unitisation, with natural character $\epsilon:A\rightarrow\mathbb C; a=(x,\lambda)\mapsto\lambda$.  Use the character to turn $E$ into a left $A$-module:
$$ a\cdot x = \epsilon(a) x \qquad (a\in A, x\in E). $$
If $(a_n)$ is weakly-null in $A$ then $\epsilon(a_n)\rightarrow 0$ and so $(a_n\cdot x_n)$ is norm-null.  Taking $(w_n)$ to be any weakly-null sequence in $E$ which is not norm-null (which exists as $E$ fails to have the Schur property) yields the counter-example.

Comment: Holy smokes, this was kind of obvious. Thank you truly for sparing your valuable time to write an answer. If I may: do we have an easy example if $A$ admits no almost periodic functionals?